# Как определить, является ли строка числом, без обработки исключения?

Tags: c#

`Convert.Toint32("ляляля")` выдаст FormatException, хотелось бы что-то вроде `Char.IsDigit()`, только для строк.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int res;
bool isInt = Int32.TryParse("ляляля", out res);
```

Comment: а если само значение не важно, вместо res можно передать что-то фиктивное?

Comment: Вместо rees можно передавать что-то фиктивное, даже если значение важно, поскольку res передается как out-параметр. Поэтому я намеренно не инициализировал его при объявлении

Comment: я неправильно спросил - что-то вроде Int32.TryParse("ляляля", null) можно сделать?

Comment: @WarHamster: нет, конечно, `out int` — это же не `int*` из C. Не откомпилируется.

Comment: >он будет гарантированно инициализирован вызываемой функцией

@VladD, разве я где-то утверждал обратное? 

>что-то вроде Int32.TryParse("ляляля", null) можно сделать?

нет. Да и зачем? Вам 4 байта жалко?

Comment: @DreamChild: а, понял, значит, я неправильно интерпретировал фразу «Поэтому я намеренно не инициализировал его при объявлении». Сорри, беру свой комментарий назад.

Answer (score 1):

Вы уже сами упомянули IsDigit так чего же проще проверить строку как раз через этот метод? Например вот так.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "ляляляля";
    bool IsDigit = str.Length == str.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).Count();
}
```

Метод предлогаю как альтернативу для TryParse.

Comment: Идея хорошая, но (1) не ловит минус, (2) не ловит переполнение (например, 500 цифр), (3) не ловит локализованных чисел (не так важно).

А ещё, ваш код проще было бы написать в таком виде:

    bool IsDigit = str.All(char.IsDigit);

Comment: Спасибо за ценный коментарий :)

Comment: с точки зрения производительности это ужас между прочим.